# Не получается изменить размер ImageButton в GridLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

Добрый день. Делаю разметку элемента списка. Никак не могу забить размер кнопки в числах (20dp на 20dp). Если в высоте ее возможно задать, то в ширине никак. Создаётся впечатление, что там перманентно висит `wrap_content`.

Сама разметка:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".layout.SushiMenu">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sushiImageView"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/sushi_test_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/item_picture_width"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <GridLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/components"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="LargeText"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>


    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Доказательство того, то ImageButton абсолютно пофиг на `layout_width`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Никак не могу сделать, чтобы справа стояла маленькая кнопочка :) .

Comment: но в коде у вас на кнопку wrap_content  и стоит, вы его меняли на android:layout_width="20dp" ?

Comment: Менял, результат не изменился

Comment: а для какой цели у вас android:layout_columnWeight, он отдает излишек места кнопке, он вам разве нужен?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать атрибут android:layout_columnWeight="1"

Comment: Заработало! Проблема была в android:layout_columnWeight="1". Нужно было его убрать. Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в `android:layout_columnWeight="1"`. Нужно было его убрать.